# F#: Accessing values of decision Union

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Is there a better way or an alternative for the `getHandRankValue` function?
Maybe without the match

```
type HandRank =
    | StraightFlush of int list
    | FourOfAKind of int list
    | FullHouse of int list
    | Flush of int list
    | Straight of int list
    | ThreeOfAKind of int list
    | TwoPair of int list
    | OnePair of int list
    | HighCard of int list
    
let getHandRankValue handRank =
    match handRank with
    | StraightFlush x -> x
    | FourOfAKind x -> x
    | FullHouse x -> x
    | Flush x -> x
    | Straight x -> x
    | ThreeOfAKind x -> x
    | TwoPair x -> x
    | OnePair x -> x
    | HighCard x -> x

let ranks = [Flush([8;6;4;3;2]); TwoPair([8;4;7]); Straight([8])]

let rankValues = ranks |> List.map getHandRankValue
```

result is `[[8;6;4;3;2]; [8;4;7]; [8]]`

Comment: Have you considered separating the two - e.g. `type Hand = Hand of HandRank * int list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the suggestion to factor out the `int list` from your type. Barring that, you can also simplify your `getHandRankValue` function somewhat, as follows:

```ml
let getHandRankValue = function
    | StraightFlush x
    | FourOfAKind x
    | FullHouse x
    | Flush x
    | Straight x
    | ThreeOfAKind x
    | TwoPair x
    | OnePair x
    | HighCard x -> x
```

I've made two changes here:

- Replaced `match handRank` with a [pattern matching function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions).
- Removed redundant `-> x` expressions.